# jQuery Mobile dynamically load attr

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dynamic, attr

First of all, it's my first question :) And i have to say, i have a bad english :) Sorry for this..

I have a problem to joomla with jquery mobile. a tags comes from joomla content. I can't insert "data-*" manuel. I have to use,

> When document ready.. "$('a').attr("data-role", "button")

But this making a problem. I will explain..

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.menu a').attr("data-role", "button").text();
        $('.menu a').attr("data-icon", "arrow-r");
        $('.menu a').attr("data-transition", "slide");
        $('.menu a').attr("data-iconpos", "right");
    })
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<scripttype="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('.menu a').attr("data-role", "button").text();
      $('.menu a').attr("data-icon", "arrow-r");
      $('.menu a').attr("data-transition", "slide");
      $('.menu a').attr("data-iconpos", "right");
    })
</script>
```

attr("data-role", "button").. is working when 'pagebeforecreate' event triggered. but jquery.mobile.js does not create "mobile link".

I hope so you understand it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code and the first thing I noticed is

```
$(function() {
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

I can't say if it's that the problem.

```
$('.menu a').attr("data-role", "button").text();
```

I noticed the text() function but I don't understand why it's there.

Comment: .text().. i forget this. not a problem; When i remove this, not working again. I did edit, but still not working.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that jQuery Mobile doesn't read from attributes set from jQuery. Can you edit them from the server language?

Comment: Exactly. My server language Php. I think you mean, "use asp, or another". i didn't try. It's not possible right now. But i can try .html pages.